# Delete (remove) Clover created EFI folder in macOS Catalina

Tags: permissions, sudo, macos-catalina, ownership

I have a couple of folders that were created by Clover when I accidentally selected my OS hard drive instead of the EFI partition when installing an update.  Now the root of my main hard drive has EFI and EFI Backups folders and I can't delete them for the life of me.

I have tried changing owner and permissions using sudo in terminal with no success.  Every file and folder come back as "Read-only file system".  I read that Apple restricted user access even more in Catalina but there must be a way to delete them, right?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution on reddit.

1. Disable SIP
   a.  Reboot into Recovery
   b.  Open Terminal and input: `csrutil disable`
   c.  Reboot
2. Open Terminal and input: `sudo mount -uw /`

This will work until reboot.  You will need to boot into Recovery one more time to enable SIP again.